# Truvativ Firex chainset replacement middle 32 tooth chainring & bolts

Tags: repair, chainring

I have a Truvativ FireX chainset from 2008ish, I'm looking for a replacement middle chainring however, no shops seem to stock replacements for Truvativ chainsets.

Just wondering if anyone has any recommendations for chainrings that should fit a Truvativ Firex chainset (i.e. is there an industry standard size for them, or do they vary).

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: In the end I couldn't find one online from a reliable source, so I went to a local bike shop, and they had one in stock (Cost more than the shimano alternatives though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this bike shop](http://www.icyclesusa.com/catalog/truvativ-firex-single-speed-crankset.htm) it takes Shimano 4 bolt 104mm/74mm BCD chainrings, so you should be able to use the Shimano rings. If you have a spare bike and the right tools, take the cranks off, remove the ring and take both into a shop. That way you/they can check the fit before you buy a chainring. It's one of those times when you're better off paying a premium for LBS service so you don't end up buying multiple wrong parts online.

I don't know how (un)common those chainrings are, but we still get them as a new stock item in Australia and there seem to be lots of hits in [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=104mm%20chainring)